# Why does it rain during the sunny day?

Tags: sun, rain

What are factors that cause rainfall while the sun is still shining. The phenomena is known as sunshower?

The information I found so far is very limited. Please help me answer this question if you know anything about it.

Comment: *The information our there is so limited*? [Wikipedia explains it perfectly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshower)

Comment: I think you need to explain just what you mean by "sunny day".  Absolutely clear, or scattered clouds?  It's quite common hereabouts, in the summer, for separated cumulonimbus clouds to build up and produce rain, while the sky remains clear between them.  Or it can be raining (or more commonly, snowing) over the nearby mountains while it's clear overhead, and the wind will blow rain from the mountains.

Comment: I doubt I could cite references for this, but I believe one form of sunshower might occur when extremely moist air is disturbed by an eddy current, thus forming a small, transient low pressure zone and allowing moisture to condense out as rain. The effect, obviously, would be very short-lived and local.

Comment: See also [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/rain-without-clouds/10328)

Comment: During the day, it is always sunny above the clouds.

Answer (score 3):

I think Wikipedia explains quite well. It is the wind that transport the airborne water droplets from a nearby showering cloud. It is quite common in UK especially near the coast which is often very windy. Usually the weather forecast will say that it has scattered shower with sunny spell.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshower